# changing margin for part of the document

Tags: margins

I want to change the margin in the middle of the page in a twoside document. The contents in this section (with new wider margin) happen to continue on to the next page. And I am having a hard time editing the correct margin for the second page. I am attaching the source code along with the output. Is there a way to make the top part of the second page to follow the margin defined in the previous page?

Specifically, I have

```
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-5cm}{0cm}
```

when I start changing the margin. When the texts run to the second page, it'll work (presumably) if I end the `adjustwidth` at the end of the first page and start another one with `\begin{adjustwidth*}(0cm}{-5cm}` at the beginning of the second page.

But I'm hoping to have a more elegant way of doing this.

Thank you

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=7cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
]
{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{changepage}% provides the adjustwidth environment

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
\item[]}{\end{list}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\columnsep{30pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\bigskip
%start changing margin
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-5cm}{0cm}
\textsf{Exercises}

\vspace{-.1in}
\noindent\rule{17cm}{0.4pt}

\vspace{-.1in}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{adjustwidth*}
%end changing margin

\lipsum[1-2]

%start changing margin
\begin{changemargin}{0cm}{-5cm}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{changemargin}
%end changing margin


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you setting margins relative to the page or the text area?  Page margin have to keep \oddsidemargin and \evensidemargin in mind.

Comment: Thanks Torbjorn. I found a way to fix this. I used the package \usepackage[innermargin=-5.0cm,]{fullwidth}